# To sort and list every word listed in the documents available to me, I need to filter out blank space from the file

Tags: bash

So I wrote a script that takes text files as arguments concatenates them into a temporary text file, and then takes every word in that file, separates it, lists it and counts how many times it appears.

The only problem left is I'm unable to filter out blank space as to separate words which throws a wrench into my code.

I've tried assigning ' ' to a variable called PUNISHED along with *, as I am trying to count words only and not symbols.

```
PUNISHED=" *' ' "

if [ -z "$@"  ]; then
        echo "You need to give this a filename."
        exit 1
elif [ "$@" > 1 ]; then
        echo  "You have more than one argument, commencing now."
fi

test -e temp.txt || echo >> temp.txt

for i in $@
do
        cat $@ > temp.txt
done
         tr ' ' '\n' < "temp.txt"| grep -v "${PUNISHED}" temp.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > result.txt | cut -c 15 result.txt
```

~

Edit: Fixed the error messaging.

Comment: Use regex instead

Comment: `for i in $@
do
        cat $@` would print each file count of files count to the temp.txt. (ie. for 3 files, it would print each file 3 times). `grep -v "${PUNISHED}" temp.txt` doesn't read standard input, doing `|` effectively discards the the output of `tr` command.

Comment: This is XY question. Your real question looks like "how to count occurences of words in a file" or similar.

Comment: Well, counting words on a group of files can be done in a one-liner: `for f in *.txt; do <"$f" tr -d '[[:punct:]]' | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]' | xargs -n 1; done | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`.

Comment: `it error messages too many` - please include the _exact_ error message at best including line numbers and filenames as printed out by bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation of your words counting script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
  echo  "You have more than one argument, commencing now."

  cat "$@" | # Output all files in arguments to stdout
    tr -d '[:punct:]' | # Remove punctuation
    tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | # Lowercase all
    xargs -n 1 | # Lay all words one by line into a words list
    sort | # Sort the words list
    uniq -c | # Count number of occurrences of words in list
    sort -k 1nr # Sort the list on the count column numerical reverse order
else
  echo "You need to give this a filename." >&2 # Output error message to stderr
  exit 1 # Exit with error code
fi
```

Comment: I read your comment earlier, you actually helped me a lot and taught me a lot. Thank you.